# Chrome driver for Selenium stuck in black screen

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I use Chrome webdriver with Selenium for web scraping on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine until after a few hours, the browser randomly gets stuck into the status of a black screen and does not do anything but wait. I need to manually refresh the browser to make it work again. Some other times the browser is dead shown by not responding to any clicking or scrolling, but is still doing the work in the back.

My question is: can I use the headless mode of Chrome webdriver to avoid this problem? I'm not sure if this is just related to the UI, and there is no way for me to tell whether the webdriver is stuck again without the UI because the problem happens randomly.

Comment: Yes, you can go ahead with that. headless mode is just to reduce execution time.

Comment: What does the trace logs say?

Comment: @DebanjanB The trace logs say nothing. It is basically stuck there, no exception or warning from the trace logs, and no progress on my work, unless I refresh the browser. Then selenium acts like nothing happened.

Comment: @cruisepandey I'm sorry I do not quite understand. If I use headless mode, can I rest assured that it will not get stuck in the same status in the backend, since I will not be able to see it?